# Retrieving Friends from Firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database with this structure:

```
/users:
    L-4ndxd58sqEwarvinW: <-- randomly generated id
        name: henk
        birthdate: 14-05-2016
    L-4ndxd58sqEdgygorW:
        name: priscilla
        birthdate: 14-05-2016

/friends:
    L-4ndxd58sqEwarvinW: <-- user id (henk)
        L-4ndxd58sqEdgygorW: true, <-- friends user id (priscilla)
        L-4ndxd58sqphysBW: true,
```

My current variables:

```
    mFriendDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("friends").child(mCurrent_user_id);
    mFriendDatabase.keepSynced(true);
    mCurrent_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Basically I want to retrieve the id's of mCurrent_user_id's friends and search the Users database for those users.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any connection between the keys in `/friends` and anything under `/users`. Based on this data structure, how can we know that the first message is from `21532761536`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry, I just typed some random stuff. I corrected my post above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
mCurrent_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
mFriendDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("friends").child(mCurrent_user_id);
DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
mFriendDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot friendKeySnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String friendKey = friendKeySnapshot.getKey();
            usersRef.child(friendKey).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot friendSnapshot) {
                    String friendName = friendSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    System.out.println(friendName);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

The nested listeners are a bit convoluted, but the flow itself should be pretty easy to follow.

Comment: @FrankvanPueffelen I don't really understand what is going on here. What is System.out.println doing to friendname? How would I put that into a ListView?